# Putting Null value to Not string column types

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to know any ideas is available.

This images shows my table and `Po_Settl` column type is bit and `Settled_` type is int.

So when user cancel the record I want to fill this again to the NULL value as shown as other rows.

As far this is done my manually, I press <kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd> to change it to the null. So any other way to do this, Here with I will show my stored procedure that I wrote this to be work, but it's not working currently.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_PayBill]
    @Req_Id int = NULL,
    @Emp_Id varchar(10) = NULL,
    @Reason varchar(50) = NULL,
    @PO_Id int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[App_Paybill]
    SET [Cancelled_By] = @Emp_Id,
        [Cancelled_Reason] = @Reason,
        [Cancelled_Date] = GETDATE(),
        [Status] = 0,
        Po_SettleID = NULL
    WHERE [Id] = @Req_Id

    DECLARE @PayType VARCHAR(03)
    SET @PayType= (SELECT [ReqType]
                   FROM [dbo].[Settleing_PaymentRequest]
                   WHERE [Payment_Id] = @Req_Id)

    UPDATE Settleing_PaymentRequest 
    SET Status = 0
    WHERE Payment_Id = @Req_Id

    IF @PayType = 'PO'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[PO_Numbers]
        SET [Po_Settled] = NULL, [Settled_By] = NULL
        WHERE Req_Id = @PO_Id
    END
    ELSE IF @PayType = 'GR'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE App_Common_Request
        SET Settled = NULL, SettlePendingStatus = NULL
        WHERE Request_Id = @PO_Id
    END
END
```

[image: SampleImage]

Comment: *"it's not working currently"* What does this mean? What happens? Do you get an error, unexpected behaviour, undesired results, something else? Help us help you. Provide us with sample data and expected results in a **consumable** format, preferably as DDL and DML statements as part of a [mre].

Comment: "it's not working currently" which I mean is when the above SP is triggered on a certain request ID, PO_Sett and Settled_ columns values remains the same. Existing values did not become to the NULL. I know you can't put string values to the int or bit data types. but I want to know in addition is there a way to reverse back the values to the NULL likewise others.  @Larnu

Comment: *Any* (scalar) data type can have the value `NULL`, as can any column, provided it's definition is defined as `NULL`able, yes.

Comment: @Larnu , So how to put back to NULL that db id 895 record

Comment: I tried this, but it's not changing anything.  ````UPDATE [dbo].[PO_Numbers]
SET [Po_Settled]=NULL ,[Settled_By]=NULL
WHERE Req_Id=@PO_Id
END````